# Html Page doesnt show Background Image even though the path is correct

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I am working on a test asp .net app and wanted to test out making a background image.
I put the Image file (Background.jpg) in a folder called images and placed it in the home folder of the view where my index.cshtml file is located then i edited the cshtml file to:

```
<img src="images/Background.jpg" alt="Sample Photo" />
```

It only shows the alt solution
The chrome command windows gives me this error:

(red X)GET https://localhost:XXXX/images/Background.jpg 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static files are stored within the project's web root directory.And the default directory is `{content root}/wwwroot`, You can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about static files.

So You need to put your images  folder into wwwroot like this:
[image]

Then try to use:

```
<img src="~/images/Background.jpg" alt="Sample Photo" />
```